# How to find the max of a column when joining 2 tables without using the rownumber function?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

There are two tables like below. The requirement here is to get the ID and the date for each alphabet in Table 1. If there are multiple entries for a alphabet, then get the entry with the latest date.

I tried joining the tables and using the row number and partition by methods to get the expected result, which works, but is there any better way to handle it?

**Table 1**

```
S.no |  Alphabet
-----|-----
1    |   A
2    |   B
3    |   C
```

**Table 2**

```
Alphabet |    ID   |    DATE 
---------|---------|----------    
A        | A1      | 21/12/2016
A        | A2      | 22/12/2016
C        | C1      | 25/12/2016
C        | C2      | 27/12/2016
C        | C3      | 24/12/2016
B        | B1      | 23/12/2016
```

**Expected Result**

```
S.no    | Alphabet   | ID    | Time
--------|------------|-------|-------
1       | A          | A2    | 22/12/2016
2       | B          | B1    | 23/12/2016
3       | C          | C2    | 27/12/2016
```

Comment: can we use limit and group by?

Comment: I guess if we use group by ultimately we are going to use row number for picking the entry. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No, `GROUP BY` is different than row number.  MySQL doesn't have a row number capability built in anyway.  I'm also not sure that row number would help with your problem, since you're not trying to number anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want through a series of joins.  Join the two tables together, and then use a second join to a subquery which finds the latest record for each alphabet.

```
SELECT t1.`s.no`,
       t1.Alphabet,
       t2.ID,
       t2.Time
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.Alphabet = t2.Alphabet
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Alphabet, MAX(TIME) AS max_time
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY Alphabet
) t3
    ON t2.Alphabet = t3.Alphabet AND
       t2.TIME = t3.max_time
```